# How to install screenshot plugin in phonagap android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use screenshot.js in my basic hello world app of phonegap.But i'm unable to take screenshot from my app.i'm trying to achieve this since three days . i tried all three methods of taking screenshot from app but failed .please help.here is my code :

```
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    // Method #1  ...which should work .but didn't
    window.plugins.Screenshot.saveScreenshot();

 // Method #2  ...
 window.plugins.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
      if(error){
        alert(error);
      }else{
        alert('ok',res.filePath); //should be path/to/myScreenshot.jpg
      }
    },'jpg',50,'myScreenShot');

 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Screenshot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

 // Method #3  ...

navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
  if(error){
    console.error(error);
  }else{
    console.log('ok',res.filePath);
  }
});
```

```
</body>
```